# Swift preferedFontSize change programmatically for accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility

I've implemented a label like this:

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

If I change text size settings from Settings > Accessibility > Larger text, my label is resized.

[image: Text Accessibility Settings, iPhone]

My question is, how do I implement this behaviour in app? Let's say I have a slider to increment the font size according to accessibility rules.
How can I change in a swift way all text accordingly? Let's say slider increase by 2 the font size of the whole app. How can I do it while keeping my systemFont? Is there a method I am missing?

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not want to use iOS's existing system to automatically adjusting your app's font size, and instead wants to make a *different* slider to do this instead? Just saying, users who would like all text to be very large would now need to change one more setting, in addition to the system built-in one.

Comment: That's a fair point. I saw different native and iOS centered app implementing this behaviour, and I was wondering if there was a native and easy way to achieve this. If the answer is no, ill think deeper about your point.

Comment: It is of course *possible* to do this, but my point is that I don't recommend doing this. You should respect the user's *system* preferences.

Comment: I really appreciate your time, and at this point I agree with you.